# How to show only first match in pcregrep?

Tags: linux, grep, pcregrep

I have xml in log-files, that looks like:

```
<ServiceRs>
1
</ServiceRs>
text text text
<ServiceRs>
2
</ServiceRs>
text
```

So, i need to cut this XML from log file and i'm trying to do this with:

```
pcregrep -M '<ServiceRs>(\n|.)*</ServiceRs>'
```

But after this i didn't get two ServiceRs xml's, i got this:

```
<ServiceRs>
1
</ServiceRs>
text text text
<ServiceRs>
2
</ServiceRs>
```

I know, that i can modify pattern - (\n|.)* -> (\n|.){0, n), but  i really don't know how many lines will be in xml.

Comment: Don't use `grep` to process XML, get `xmlstarlet`.

Comment: @Barmar i can use only default redhat packeges, coz i have no perms for install any app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try

`pcregrep -M '<ServiceRs>(\n|.)*?</ServiceRs>'`

`?` is for lazy match

It only matches the content between the `<ServiceRs>` and `</ServiceRs>` and excludes the rest `text text...`s

Ref: https://regexr.com/3h1ug